# How to install a Python package that does not exist in Anaconda Cloud

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I use Anaconda as the main source of python packages and also my main interpreter in PyCharm. If I want to install any package, I go to `Anaconda Cloud` and find it immediately something like [this](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/matplotlib). Now, I want to install a package that only exists in Python Package Index [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nonblock). I cannot find it in `Anaconda Cloud` so I don't know how to install it. Do I just need to include the package folder in the project directory in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [install non-conda packages](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages) using pip:

```
pip install python-nonblock
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've never known about that.